# PHP imap_open() error in command line

Tags: php, command-line, imap

I am trying to run a PHP page from the command line which uses imap_open() to open an email inbox. The script works fine in the browser.

PHP Script:

```
$imap_stream    = imap_open($host,$username,$pass);
```

Command:

```
php -c /etc/php.ini /home/public_html/inc/mailGet.php
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imap_open() in /home/public_html/inc/mailGet.php on line 13
```

I included the correct php.ini with `-c /etc/php.ini` in the command to make sure it was using the same .ini file as the browser. (this is the path to the .ini as stated in my phpinfo(); page).

I am running Apache2(Centos5.5) with PHP 5.2.6. Can anybody please advise?

Thank you,

Chris.

Comment: what happens when you don't specify the ini file? The error indicates the IMAP extension isn't loaded. What does `php --ri imap` give you?

Comment: @Aaron - Hi. php --ri imap produces 'Extension 'imap' not present.'. Without the ini file specified, the PHP errors higher up the page with mysql_connect() function.

Comment: This is probably better suited on serverfault.com, voting to migrate there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found i need to define the extension sometimes in my php.ini when using CLI-PHP. Try adding extension=imap.so to your php.ini and still include it with your command (-c /etc/php.ini)

I had to do the same thing for mysql by adding extension=mysql.so

Even though the extension will show in your phpinfo(); it doesnt always load in CLI PHP.

Comment: @pagwil - I works perfectly. Still not too sure why it doesn't work without? But, it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The IMAP functions are an extension. According to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imap.installation.php), PHP needs to have been compiled with `--with-imap[=DIR]` it doesn't seem to be in your case.

Maybe you have multiple instances of command line `php` on your system?

As a last straw, if CLI PHP can't be equipped with the needed functions, I guess you could do a http request in your crontab:

```
wget http://localhost/path_to_script.php
```

Comment: @Pekka - I am able to use the IMAP functions in the browser. Does this mean that PHP is complied with IMAP functions?

Comment: @Christopher it could be that you have multiple PHP binaries on your system. You could try [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/58346/how-to-determine-which-php-is-being-used) to find out where yours is. If PHP is configured as an Apache module, there may not be a php binary with IMAP enabled at all.

Comment: @Pekka, I have located the PHP binary to /usr/local/bin/php. As I am stating the same .ini file in the command that I use in the browser, why would it work in the browser, and not in the command line?

Comment: @Christopher I'm no expert here, but as far as I know, the ini file is not enough on *nix systems: The PHP binary needs to actually have been compiled with the needed extensions. Only on Windows can you enable/disable extensions at will by changing php.ini. If @Aaron's --ri idea yields "not present", you probably have a binary that isn't equipped with the imap extension. You would need to find one that is, or if that isn't present, recompile

Comment: @Pekka - Right OK, that makes sense. How would I know if the location stated in the command line "/usr/local/bin/php" is different to that used by the browser?

Comment: @Christopher depending on how PHP is configured, there may not be a PHP binary in the browser, but an Apache module. You would have to find all files named `php` on your system - I don't know how to do that on Linux, though, `locate php` will give too much I think. Your latter question I don't know the answer to. I added another workaround idea to my answer

Comment: OK, thank you. I will look into it further and explore the workaround as a last resort. Thanks again.